# Not sure how to categorize this question in triage

Tags: discussion, triage

[How to add link to image with Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50531519/how-to-add-link-to-image-with-javascript)

The question is very confusing. The author has already created an `<img>` element, added attributes *and* appended it to another element, yet they're asking how to create an `<a>` element, add attributes and do basically the same thing.

It's not *exactly* a duplicate; it's not *exactly* unsalvageable (at least as far as I'm reading the definition of that category). The comments are trying to be nice and help the author realize they're asking how to do the same thing they just posted code to do.

How should this be handled?

Comment: This is my first time in the triage queue, so I'm trying to get a handle on it.

Comment: Note that the skip button is there for a reason. Especially when you're a starting reviewer, you can use it a lot. You can just only review questions where you're sure, and skip the rest.

Comment: That question boils down to "does the link go in the image, or does the image go in the link?".

Comment: @ErikvonAsmuth I think that's good advice. In this case, I was trying to spend a bit more time thinking about these options as I'm getting used to how this works. I definitely foresee more skipping in the future.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

"Unsalvageable" means that a person *other* than the OP cannot edit the question to be reasonably scoped or on-topic.

In all reality you have the answer on what you should do here:

> The question is very confusing.

Sounds like a straightforward "unclear what you're asking" close vote.

Comment: That seems probably right. That said, from the triage view, I can't really get to that unless I do something that seems very "hacky" and likely a site bug (click Unsalvageable, click Duplicate [flag breadcrumb appears], click back to Closing). From the triage queue, should I just skip it?

Comment: If you are ever nervous or uncertain about a review, don't hesitate to skip it @Shibumi.   It's better to skip than to do a bad review.

Comment: I think that's probably the best sentiment. Especially with two people suggesting it :D. Thanks for the response.

Comment: @Shibumi You don't need to click the duplicate close reason.  Just click on the should be closed reason to flag a question for closure.

Comment: @ServyI suppose you're suggesting I just go to the question directly rather than trying to flag from the triage interface?

Comment: @Shibumi:  You can do this just fine from the triage queue - you don't have to go to the question proper.

Comment: TL:dr this word doesn't mean what you think it means, but something no one could imagine it means (cc @Shibumi)